# Is there any tool available to dynamically create a kind of sequence diagram depicting different stages/flow between components of a systems

Tags: java

I am developing a java based web application that requires me to generate a sequence diagram with input from an SIP(Session Initiation Protocol) message. I have to represent the call flow between different phones and corresponding servers. Is there any tool I can leverage to achieve this kind of functionality. The diagram has to be generated on the run as there maybe multiple SIP messages the user can choose. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

- http://yuml.me/
- http://www.websequencediagrams.com/index.php

Those are online diagram generators (with API).

Comment: This is a sample SIP message. I dont think the generators above would be of any help.                                          INVITE sip:user2@server2.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP pc33.server1.com;branch=z9hG4bK776asdhds Max-Forwards: 70 
To: user2 <sip:user2@server2.com>
From: user1 <sip:user1@server1.com>;tag=1928301774
Call-ID: a84b4c76e66710@pc33.server1.com 
CSeq: 314159 INVITE 
Contact: <sip:user1@pc33.server1.com>
Content-Type: application/sdp 
Content-Length: 142